# Compute multiple Integral and plot them (with R)

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I'm having trouble to compute and then plot multiple integral. It would be great if you could help me.

So I have this function

```
> f = function(x, mu = 30, s = 12){dnorm(x, mu, s)}
```

which i want to integrate multiple time between z(1:100) to +Inf  to plot that with x=z and y = auc  :

```
> auc = Integrate(f, z, Inf)
```

R return :

```
Warning message:
In if (is.finite(lower)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I have tested to do a loop :

```
while(z < 100){
z = 1
auc = integrate(f,z,Inf)
z = z+1}
```

Doesn't work either ... don't know what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is actually somewhat subtle, and in a certain sense gets to the core of how R works, so here is a slightly longer explanation.

R is a "vectorized" language, which means that just about everything works on vectors. If I have 2 vectors `A` and `B`, then `A+B` is the element-by-element sum of `A` and `B`. Nearly all R functions work this way also. If `X` is a vector, then `Y <- exp(X)` is also a vector, where each element of `Y` is the exponential of the corresponding element of `X`.

The function `integrate(...)` is one of the few functions in R that is *not* vectorized. So when you write:

```
f   <- function(x, mu = 30, s = 12){dnorm(x, mu, s)}
auc <- integrate(f, z, Inf)
```

the `integrate(...)` function does not know what to do with z when it is a vector. So it takes the first element and complains. Hence the warning message.

There is a special function in R, `Vectorize(...)` that turns scalar functions into vectorized functions. You would use it this way:

```
f   <- function(x, mu = 30, s = 12){dnorm(x, mu, s)}
auc <- Vectorize(function(z) integrate(f,z,Inf)$value)
z   <- 1:100
plot(z,auc(z), type="l")   # plot lines
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer , it made much more sens now:)

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to do the integrating by hand.  `pnorm` gives the integral from negative infinity to the input for the normal density.  You can get the upper tail instead by modifying the lower.tail parameter

```
z <- 1:100
y <- pnorm(z, mean = 30, sd = 12, lower.tail = FALSE)
plot(z, y)
```

If you're looking to integrate more complex functions then using `integrate` will be necessary - but if you're just looking to find probabilities for distributions then there will most likely be a function built in that does the integration for you directly.

Comment: Oh , ok, I understand more the first one, but yours seems more elegant ... Thanks a lot :)